# Translating “beschränkt” in a mathematical/physical context

Tags: translation, german-to-english, mathematics

Wolfgang Paul (not Wolfgang Pauli, another Nobel Prize winner) wrote a three-page article which got him a Nobel prize in 1989: *Ein neues Massenspektrometer ohne Magnetfeld*. It contains the following sentence:

> Diese Gl. (3) hat nur in gewissen Bereichen der Parameter *λ* und *q* sog. „stabile" Lösungen, d. h. Lösungen, die bei beliebigen Anfangsbedingungen für alle Werte von *ζ* beschränkt bleiben.

I was trying to machine-translate a portion of it for quoting it in an article, but the symbols mess up. If I crudely translate it myself I arrive at:

> This equation (3) has in only certain ranges of the parameter *λ* and *q* so-called stable solutions, i.e. solutions, at arbitrary beginning conditions for all values of *ζ* remain limited.

DeepL’s translation is:

> This equation (3) only has so-called “stable” solutions in certain ranges of the parameters *λ* and *q*, i.e. solutions that remain limited for all values of *ζ* under any initial conditions.

I am not happy with *limited* as a translation for *beschränkt* here, as it does not make sense to me. What does it mean here and how could I translate it?

Comment: I removed your second question since it is independent of the first one, that was already answered. Please ask it separately.

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer for identifying relative pronouns from another book. The word order changes and the verb is at the end.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> i.e. solutions that are [**bounded**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function) for all values of *zeta* under any initial conditions.

Solutions to differential equations can be distinguished in *bounded* and *unbounded* cases.

---

In case like these (also in the reverse case, where you need a technical term translated from English to German), it often helps looking for the term in the localized versions of Wikipedia. [This German article about 'Beschränktheit'](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beschr%C3%A4nktheit) is linked to [an English article about 'Bounded set'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set).

Comment: That was a good tip. Is there is way to identify when the definite article is serving as a "relative pronoun" "solutions that are..." How do we recognize that die here is a relative pronoun?